# A LIFO data structure that holds max N items

Tags: java

In java, which LIFO data structure class allows me to specify a MAX item size which automatically discards old items whenever adding an item will cause it to exceed MAX size.

Comment: An array organized as a circular buffer?..

Comment: I don't know Java, but you can write a class to control your inputs,outputs and checks like a collection object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass `Stack` to get the desired behavior. You just need to override `push()` to check whether the size is greater than N, and discard old items:

```
@Override
public void push(E elt) {
    super.push(elt);
    while (this.size() > this.maxSize) {
        this.removeElementAt(this.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

will probably be close to what you want.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't such a data structure in java api! guess i will just go with ur method.

Comment: This is what I used when I had to do the same thing. Might I ask why you need it?

Comment: i have streaming updates and need to buffer the last 10 updates and take the latest update and flush the rest

Comment: Hmm, what about adding `synchronized` to that method?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such structure in Java. I hope this custom implementation serves your needs:

```
    BlockingDeque<Object> deque = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Object>(32) {
        public void push(Object e) {
            final java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock lock;
            try {
                Field lockField = LinkedBlockingDeque.class.getDeclaredField("lock");
                lockField.setAccessible(true);
                lock = (ReentrantLock) lockField.get(this);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e1);
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e1);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e1);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e1);
            }
            lock.lock();
            try {
                if (!offerFirst(e)) {
                    pollLast();
                    offerFirst(e);
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    };
```

Then you use it like a Stack (Deque replaces the old Stack class):

```
    deque.push(new Object());
    Object o = deque.pop();
```

Sorry for all the lock stuff, but it was needed to avoid inconsistencies.