# Java Stack with elements limit

Tags: java, list, stack

I know this question has asked many times but  after seaching for an hour i still have problem.

I want to use a lifo stack which has a max number of elements it can store.After it reach the max number is deletes the element at first place  and replace it with the new so in first pop i can get this element and in second i have to get the element at size-1.

What i tried:

**1)** Using a modified Stack ,as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359802/a-lifo-data-structure-that-holds-max-n-items) .The problem is that it always returning the first 5 elements(if the size is 5) i added.

```
class StackSizable<E> extends Stack<E>{

    int maxSize;
    StackSizable(int size)
    {
        super();
        this.maxSize=size;
    }

    @Override
    public E push(E elt) {
        super.push(elt);
        while (this.size() > this.maxSize) {
            this.removeElementAt(this.size() - 1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**2**)Using an ArrayDeque ,i dont see any diference from a simple Stack , its not setting any limit(am i using it wrong?)

```
ArrayDeque<State> lifo = new ArrayDeque<State>(5);
lifo.pop();
lifo.push(state);
```

I want to use this in a puzzle game for undo-redo functionality

**Solved:** I ended using a fixed size stack as tom said ,mainly for the performance

`public class FixedStack<T> {
     private T[] stack;
     private int size;
     private int top;
     private int popBalance = 0;//its used to see if all the elements have been popped

     public FixedStack(T[] stack) {
           this.stack = stack;
           this.top = 0;
           this.size = stack.length;
     }

     public void push(T obj) {
           if (top == stack.length)top = 0;
           stack[top] = obj;
           top++;
           if (popBalance < size - 1)popBalance++;
     }

     public T pop() {

          if (top - 1 < 0)top = size;
          top--;
          T ob = stack[top];
          popBalance--;
          return ob;
     }

     public void clear() {
          top = 0;
     }

     public int size() {
          return size;
     }

     public boolean poppedAll() {
          if (popBalance == -1)return true;
          return false;
     }
}`

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727919/creating-a-fixed-size-stack

Comment: @JerryAndrews Except he wants something that deletes the first element when it reaches capacity, so I think something like that, but which wraps around is better (added below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most efficient way to this is with a fixed array, with size equal to your max # of elements, and an index that points to the element that is currently the 'top' of the queue.

When you add a new element you add it at index+1 (wrapping back to element 0 if necessary) and possibly overwriting an element that no longer fits.  When you pop an element you do the reverse.

This way your data structure never has to be re-ordered, and you can use an array which is more light-weight then a collection.

Answer (score 3):

When the maximum size has been reached, your line

```
this.removeElementAt(this.size() - 1);
```

then immediately removes the last pushed element (which you just pushed), which is the top of the stack.  You need to remove the first element instead (bottom of the stack):

```
this.removeElementAt(0);
```

Comment: yep you are right that was the problem i changed it and it works correct,but i will go with tom's answer mainly for the performance.

Comment: That's fine, @Tom's answer will perform better and so is the better answer.